# ng-src does not update iframe on url parameter change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have the following in my view:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%;height: 240px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ng-src="{{previewUrl}}">
</iframe>
```

and I use the following code to set previewUrl

```
$scope.previewUrl = test ? '/foo/bar/' : '/foo/bar/?test=1';
```

Test is changed elsewhere during the lifetime of my angular app and I want the iframe's source to update accordingly.

It seems, that because the only difference is in a URL parameter the change is being ignored by angular.

If I change the code to this:

```
$scope.previewUrl = test ? '/foo/bar/' : '/foo/bar/baz/';
```

everything works.

Is this a bug in angularjs or am I missing something?
**I am using angular version 1.2.5**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may need to use the `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` to make it work.

Based on your example, the change you need to do is,

```
$scope.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(test ? '/foo/bar/' : '/foo/bar/baz/');
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use "$sce" service to resolve your issue as below.

```
// in Controller 

app.controller('TestWorkController', function ($scope, $sce) { 
$scope.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(true ? 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm' : 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm');
});

//View
  <iframe style="width: 100%;height: 240px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ng-src="{{previewUrl}}"></iframe>
```